# for each group by date in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

which pulls data from and reformats it.

```
Promise = require "bluebird"
request = Promise.promisify require "request"
moment = require "moment"
cdn = require('config').server.cloudFrontDomain
toTitleCase = require "titlecase"

exports.getStocks = (path) ->
  return new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
    request path
      .then (body) ->
        germanStock = []
        germanStocks = JSON.parse body.body
        germanStocks.forEach (stock) ->
          obj = {}
          this.parsePart = (remaining) ->
            value = remaining.value
            dashIndex = value.lastIndexOf '-'
            if dashIndex != -1
              remaining.value = value.substring 0, dashIndex - 1
              return value.substring(dashIndex + 1).trim()
            else 
              return ''

          remaining = 
            value: stock.name
          size = parsePart remaining
          colour = parsePart remaining
          name = remaining.value
          sku = stock.sku
          styleId = sku.split(/-/)[0]
          colorcode = /^(.*)-(.*)([0-9])$/.exec(sku)?[2]
          bgStyle = "url(//#{cdn}/assets/product_shots/thumbs/#{styleId}-#{colorcode}.jpg)"

          obj.id = sku
          obj.name = name
          obj.colorUrl = bgStyle
          obj.colour = toTitleCase(colour.toLowerCase())
          obj.size = size
          obj.stock = stock.stock
          obj.inProduction = ''
          obj.office = 'DE'

          stock.preorders.forEach (i, idx) ->
            date = moment(i.date).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
            if idx != stock.preorders.length - 1
              obj.inProduction = obj.inProduction.concat i.amount + ' due on ' + date + ', '
            else
              obj.inProduction = obj.inProduction.concat i.amount + ' due on ' + date
          germanStock.push obj
        resolve germanStock

      .catch (err) -> 
        reject err
```

where my data is like:

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "stamp":"2014-09-25T12:55:30Z",
   "name":" MENS T-SHIRT - BRIGHT BLUE - XS",
   "sku":"SS01-BB0",
   "stock":81,
   "active":true,
   "preorders":[  
      {  
         "id":92549,
         "amount":160,
         "date":"2016-06-19T22:00:00Z"
      },
      {  
         "id":92549,
         "amount":200,
         "date":"2016-06-19T22:00:00Z"
      },
      {  
         "id":92549,
         "amount":1000,
         "date":"2016-06-21T22:00:00Z"
      }
   ],
   "discountMatrix":0.0,
   "stockNormalized":81,
   "preOrdersSum":1360
},
{  
   "id":2,
   "stamp":"2014-09-25T12:55:30Z",
   "name":" MENS T-SHIRT - BRIGHT BLUE - S",
   "sku":"SS01-BB1",
   "stock":339,
   "active":true,
   "preorders":[  
      {  
         "id":92551,
         "amount":240,
         "date":"2016-06-19T22:00:00Z"
      },
      {  
         "id":92438,
         "amount":160,
         "date":"22016-06-19T22:00:00Z"
      }
   ],
   "discountMatrix":0.0,
   "stockNormalized":339,
   "preOrdersSum":400
},
```

what is the correct way to group each `preorders` quantity that is on the same date, so that instead of getting:

`160 due on 19-06-2016, 200 due on 19-06-2016, 1000 due on 21-06-2016`

i get `360 due on 19-06-2016, 1000 due on 21-06-2016`

any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use an object with the date as key and the total amount for the date as value.

For each preorder, add it's amount at it's date index in this object. At the end of the iteration print the content of the object:

```
moment = require "moment"

data = [
  {
    id:1
    stamp: "2014-09-25T12:55:30Z"
    name: " MENS T-SHIRT - BRIGHT BLUE - XS"
    sku: "SS01-BB0"
    stock:81
    active:true
    preorders:[
      {
         id:92549
         amount:160
         date: "2016-06-19T22:00:00Z"
      }
      {
         id:92549
         amount:200
         date: "2016-06-19T22:00:00Z"
      }
      {
         id:92549
         amount:1000
         date: "2016-06-21T22:00:00Z"
      }
    ]
    discountMatrix:0.0
    stockNormalized:81
    preOrdersSum:1360
  }
]

obj = {}
obj.inProduction = ""
amountByDate = {}

# for each document in your data
for doc in data
  # for each preorder in your document
  for preorder in doc.preorders
    # add it's amount in the index equals to it's date
    if amountByDate[preorder.date]
      amountByDate[preorder.date] += preorder.amount
    else
      # or create the index with the value if it doesn't exist
      amountByDate[preorder.date] = preorder.amount

for date, amount of amountByDate
  if obj.inProduction != ""
    obj.inProduction = obj.inProduction.concat ", #{amount} due on #{moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}"
  else
    obj.inProduction = obj.inProduction.concat "#{amount} due on #{moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}"

console.log obj.inProduction
```

Result:

> 360 due on 20-06-2016, 1000 due on 22-06-2016